# Pragmatic Agile Web Dev with Rails : how to run this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm reading the Pragmatic rails app book and running into a pb when the books says 'Run this code'.

My problem is how to run the `Account.creation.do` block code? How to run this?. The console only accepts one line. Link to the file below.

```
So, now let’s write the code to transfer money between two accounts. It’s pretty straightforward:

peter = Account.create(:balance => 100, :number => "12345")
paul  = Account.create(:balance => 200, :number => "54321")
Account.transaction do 
  paul.deposit(10)
  peter.withdraw(10)
end

We check the database, and, sure enough, the money got transferred:
depot> sqlite3 -line db/development.sqlite3 "select * from accounts" 
  id = 1
  number = 12345
  balance = 90

  id = 2
  number = 54321
  balance = 210
```

[Transactions file example](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/rails4/code/rails30/e1/ar/transactions.rb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type it all in one line if you want:

```
Account.transaction do; paul.deposit(10); peter.withdraw(10); end
```

The `;` is to be used to separate multiple statements on one line.

But IRB should allow you to type multiple lines as well. Try that too after you have done the above.

Comment: Thanks. Solved (but more problems ahead :)

Comment: by chance do you know why `transactions.rb` is outside the app folder and why is there `ar`folder? (Should I have the same. If so how do I generate such thing)?